# How to access data of parent's scope? eg: child.$parent.id

Tags: model, scope, angularjs

My example is superficial, the short of it I'm trying to access the parent data of the current scope of what I have:

I have a bunch of tasks I'm watching. I need to watch on when task.data changes

```
<div ng-repeat='task in tasks'>
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='task.data' />
</div>
```

but I need to update the task based on its id, so I was thinking something like child.$parent

```
exp = 'tasks.task[0].data'
$scope.$watch exp, (old_val,new_val,child)=>
  if new_value is 'something'
    id = child.$parent.id
    @MyService.do_stuff id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to access the parent scope in most cases. In your case, I'm not sure why you'd want to. If you just need to react to a change, why not something like this:

```js
$scope.checkTask = function( id ) {
  MyService.do( id )
};
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.data" ng-change="checkTask(task.id)" />
</div>
```